# How to float a view over all the activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, youtube

Inside an android app, is there any way that I can make a view float over all the activities? The official youtube android app has this feature. The video player stays on the bottom right of the screen while i'm browsing other parts of the app. I know it can be done if the app is designed with a single activity and lots of fragments. Is it possible that the youtube app is actually using only a single activity?

Comment: One way you can achieve this thing, is by having only one actual activity and having methods that are "drawing and re-drawing" the items on your screen.But it now depends on a lot of things.Like ,for example, how optimized would it be for you to go on this path. On the other hand, I would try to see if when I start a new activity ,the old one "shuts down" or not.Perhaps you can have some sort of custom Layout that is let's say half of the screen but it is actually a new activity and while this activity is started, perhaps you can still access the first activity.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches:
1. use only one Activity and Fragments.
2. use Activities and use `WindowManager`to add a view to window

Comment: Hi @rainash I want my view to float over only over my app. Not all the other apps. Is that possible with WindowManager?

Comment: In order to use the WindowManager, the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission is needed. I checked the youtube app permissions and this is not listed there. So, I guess they are using the single activity approach.

Comment: @syloc of course, when top Activity stoped or destroyed you remove it